# Version control over multiple FTP servers

Tags: git, svn, ftp, version

I have a few PHP classes which I use on many web servers, using different hosting providers and therefore I've got only FTP access to them. I'm having a hard time updating the classes whenever I update the classes, needing to login on each ftp account and updating the files.

Has anyone been through a similar situation and found a solution?

Comment: i try to get only accounts that provide SSH and then you can use rsync or rdist to keep all your remote servers updated.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad, but since it's tagged `git` I'll look at it from this perspective.

If you maintain your website projects in Git, or maintain your class library (or whatever it is in PHP) in Git, you could use a specialized Git → FTP tool, [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/git-ftp), which can be used to update remote directories via FTP from Git repositories. It works by keeping a file in the remote directory which records the commit ID with which the last synchronisation has been made, so the next synchronisation will only update/delete/modify those files/directories which have been actually changed.

Comment: This is certainly an option, but I don't use git. I'll consider using it after this though.